# SASS compiles empty CSS file?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to compile this small piece of SCSS to CSS:

```
$font-size: 16px;
$em: $font-size / 1em;

$column: 48px;
$gutter: 24px;

 $cols1: ( 1 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols2: ( 2 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols3: ( 3 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols4: ( 4 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols5: ( 5 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols6: ( 6 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols7: ( 7 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols8: ( 8 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols9: ( 9 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols10: (10 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols11: (11 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols12: (12 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols13: (13 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols14: (14 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols15: (15 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols16: (16 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
```

Tried it with both `sass grid.scss grid.css` and `sass --watch grid.scss:grid.css` - all I get is a blank css file. What's going on?

Comment: What are you expecting the css file to contain? All you're doing in the scss file is defining variables which won't be output in the css file until you use them inside a css rule.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated by @pjumble comment, you are only defining variables.  Taking your code and adding the additional `hello_world` statement:

```
$font-size: 16px;
$em: $font-size / 1em;

$column: 48px;
$gutter: 24px;

 $cols1: ( 1 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols2: ( 2 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols3: ( 3 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols4: ( 4 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols5: ( 5 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols6: ( 6 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols7: ( 7 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols8: ( 8 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
 $cols9: ( 9 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols10: (10 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols11: (11 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols12: (12 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols13: (13 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols14: (14 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols15: (15 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;
$cols16: (16 * ($column + $gutter) - $gutter) / $em;

.hello_world{ width: $column }
```

The command `sass grid.scss grid.css` produces:

```
.hello_world {
  width: 48px; }
```

Comment: Consider bumping **@pjumble**'s comment on the original question as he identified the problem before I answered the question.

Comment: Done, thanks. I expected `$font-size: 16px;` to be compiled to `font-size: 16px;`at the very least, but I see what you mean.